# Unparseable Date Error when parsing UTC string through SimpleDateFormat to Date

Tags: java, android, parsing, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to write something that will take in a string with the below format in UTC time and format it to the local time zone grabbed from the phone. However, despite looking at [SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), I'm running across the error that my sample string is unparseable:

```
W/System.err﹕ java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-07-16T21:00:00:000+0000" (at offset 19)
W/System.err﹕ at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:555)
[...]
D/Set time:﹕ Wed Jul 16 15:10:03 PDT 2014
D/TimeInMilli:﹕ 1405548603565
```

Code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone(); //Get phone's PST zone

String UTCinput = "2014-07-16T21:00:00:000+0000"; //2:00PM PST
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
format.setTimeZone(tz);

Date dateCal = new Date();

try {
    dateCal = format.parse(UTCinput);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

cal.setTime(dateCal);
Log.d("Set time: ", String.valueOf(dateCal));
Log.d("TimeInMilli: ", String.valueOf(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
```

What is the issue with the way I'm parsing?

Comment: When running into this kind of mystery, copy-paste example code. StackOverflow.com abounds with examples of SimpleDateFormat code you could have tried before posting.

Comment: Tip: Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) libraries rather than java.util.Date & SimpleDateFormat which are notoriously troublesome. You can pass your [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant string directly without need for formatting/converting.  `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2014-07-16T21:00:00:000+0000" );`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your input `String` needs to match your `DateFormat` pattern

```
String UTCinput = "2014-07-16T21:00:00.000+0000"; //2:00PM PST
                                      ^--- was ":"
```