# How to change start offset for topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, offset

It is possible to change the start offset for a new topic? I would like to create a new topic and start reading from the offset `10000`. How?

Comment: Is it possible ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do this with the help of the zookeeper shell. Kafka uses zookeeper to track the consumer offsets.

Go to kafka bin directory and invoke zookeeper shell.(my kafka version is 0.8.0)

```
./zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181
```

Now use the zookeeper get command

```
get /consumers/consumer_group_id/offsets/topic/0
```

it shows something like

```
2043
cZxid = 0x4d
ctime = Wed Mar 18 03:56:32 EDT 2015
...
```

Here 2043 is the maximum offset consumed. Set it to desired value by using zookeeper set command

```
set /consumers/consumer_group_id/offsets/topic/0 10000
```

The path is framed like this /consumers/[consumer_group_id]/offsets/[topic]/[partition_id].

You will have to substitute with appropriate consumer group, topic and partition id.

*Also since you mentioned it's a new instance of kafka, I am not sure whether consumers would have connected and consumer groups created.

Answer (score 133):

Since kafka [0.11.0.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4743) you can use the script `kafka-consumer-groups.sh`
Example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45671537/3517383)

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server kafka-host:9092 --group my-group --reset-offsets --to-earliest --all-topics --execute
```

Other options listed in the [KIP-122: Add Reset Consumer Group Offsets tooling](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-122%3A+Add+Reset+Consumer+Group+Offsets+tooling)

```
.----------------------.-----------------------------------------------.----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.
|      Scenario        |                   Arguments                   |                                                                    Example                                                                   |
:----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:
| Reset to Datetime    |  --to-datetime YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:SS.sss±hh:mm  |  Reset to first offset since 01 January 2017, 00:00:00 hrs: --reset-offsets –group test.group --topic foo --to-datetime 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z |
:----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:
| Reset by Duration    |  --by-duration  PnDTnHnMnS                    |  Reset to first offset since one week ago (from current timestamp): --reset-offsets --group test.group --topic foo --by-duration P7D         |
:----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:
| Reset to Earliest    |  --to-earliest                                |  Reset to earliest offset available: --reset-offsets --group test.group --topic foo --to-earliest                                            |
:----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:
| Reset to Latest      |  --to-latest                                  |  Reset to latest offset available: --reset-offsets --group test.group --topic foo --to-latest                                                |
:----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:
| Reset to Offset      |  --to-offset                                  |  Reset to offset 1 in all partitions: --reset-offsets --group test.group --topic foo --to-offset 1                                           |
:----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:
| Shift Offset by 'n'  |  --shift-by n                                 |  Reset to current offset plus 5 positions: --reset-offsets --group test.group –topic foo --shift-by 5                                        |
:----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:
| Reset from File      |  --from-file PATH_TO_FILE                     |  Reset using a file with reset plan: --reset-offsets --group test.group --from-file reset-plan.csv                                           |
'----------------------'-----------------------------------------------'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

You can also define the partition you want to reset, example:

- Reset offset of topic foo partition 0 to 1

  `--reset-offsets --group test.group --topic foo:0 --to-offset 1`
- Reset offset of topic foo partition 0,1,2 to earliest

  `--reset-offsets --group test.group --topic foo:0,1,2 --to-earliest`

**Reminder**: don't forget the `--execute` flag (see the execution options in the KIP). Without this flag the script  *will only print out the result of the scenario by scope*, for example:

```
TOPIC                 PARTITION NEW-OFFSET NEW-LAG LOG-END-OFFSET CONSUMER-ID HOST CLIENT-ID
foo                   0         90         10      100            -           -    -
```

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47479799/3517383).
Table created with [ascii tables](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Comment: A note that should be mentioned is that your Consumer Group must be considered inactive for this to work otherwise it won't apply any changes.

Answer (score 7):

if you need to change the offset.

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server {url} \
--topic {topic} \
--group {consumer} \
--reset-offsets --to-datetime 2020-11-11T00:00:00.000+0900 \
--execute
```

[Unparseable Date Error when parsing UTC string through SimpleDateFormat to Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791823/unparseable-date-error-when-parsing-utc-string-through-simpledateformat-to-date)

Answer (score 5):

Since kafka 0.9 offsets are stored in a topic. To change offset, use the [seek() method](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seek(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition,%20long)):

```
public void seek(TopicPartition partition, long offset)
```

> Overrides the fetch offsets that the consumer will use on the next `poll(timeout)`. If this API is invoked for the same partition more than once, the latest offset will be used on the next poll(). Note that you may lose data if this API is arbitrarily used in the middle of consumption, to reset the fetch offsets