# How to change the kafka offset with the new consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka consumer that has fallen significantly behind and, having scaled it up, I just want to move move the offset forward. This question ([How to change start offset for topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791268/how-to-change-start-offset-for-topic)) address this for the old consumers, but not for when you are using the new consumer.

Is there a command line tool for setting the offset for a consumer using the new consumer?

Comment: Can you change the consumer group ID and use auto offset reset as latest? There's no command line tool but the API has some built-in support. Check out controlling the consumer position in the javadoc https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Comment: Looks like there is an open issue for this. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4743