# How reset a consumer group in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Not sure if the title is right... Anyway suppose I've the following scenario (this happens a lot when running tests):

- A consumer starts on a topic with a single partition and with group id test
- I kill the consumer without using `close()`
- I restart the same test.

The consumer starts to output some logs:

```
2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG NetworkClient:476 - Completed connection to node 1003
    2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG NetworkClient:640 - Sending metadata request {topics=[ByjSIH]} to node 1003
    2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG Metadata:180 - Updated cluster metadata version 3 to Cluster(nodes = [192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = ByjSIH, partition = 0, leader = 1003, replicas = [1003,], isr = [1003,]])
    2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:476 - Sending coordinator request for group RHAdpuiv to broker 192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)
    2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:489 - Received group coordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1492686106738, disconnected=false, request=ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@2bea5ab4, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=10,api_version=0,correlation_id=3,client_id=consumer-1}, body={group_id=RHAdpuiv}), createdTimeMs=1492686106738, sendTimeMs=1492686106738), responseBody={error_code=15,coordinator={node_id=-1,host=,port=-1}})
    2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG NetworkClient:640 - Sending metadata request {topics=[ByjSIH]} to node 1003
    2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG Metadata:180 - Updated cluster metadata version 4 to Cluster(nodes = [192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = ByjSIH, partition = 0, leader = 1003, replicas = [1003,], isr = [1003,]])
    2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:476 - Sending coordinator request for group RHAdpuiv to broker 192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)
    2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:489 - Received group coordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1492686106840, disconnected=false, request=ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@3d8314f0, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=10,api_version=0,correlation_id=5,client_id=consumer-1}, body={group_id=RHAdpuiv}), createdTimeMs=1492686106839, sendTimeMs=1492686106839), responseBody={error_code=15,coordinator={node_id=-1,host=,port=-1}})
    2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG NetworkClient:640 - Sending metadata request {topics=[ByjSIH]} to node 1003
    2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG Metadata:180 - Updated cluster metadata version 5 to Cluster(nodes = [192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = ByjSIH, partition = 0, leader = 1003, replicas = [1003,], isr = [1003,]])
    2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:476 - Sending coordinator request for group RHAdpuiv to broker 192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)
    2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:489 - Received group coordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1492686106941, disconnected=false, request=ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@2df32bf7, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=10,api_version=0,correlation_id=7,client_id=consumer-1}, body={group_id=RHAdpuiv}), createdTimeMs=1492686106940, sendTimeMs=1492686106940), responseBody={error_code=15,coordinator={node_id=-1,host=,port=-1}})
    2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG NetworkClient:640 - Sending metadata request {topics=[ByjSIH]} to node 1003
    2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG Metadata:180 - Updated cluster metadata version 6 to Cluster(nodes = [192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = ByjSIH, partition = 0, leader = 1003, replicas = [1003,], isr = [1003,]])
    2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:476 - Sending coordinator request for group RHAdpuiv to broker 192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)
    2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:489 - Received group coordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1492686107042, disconnected=false, request=ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@530612ba, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=10,api_version=0,correlation_id=9,client_id=consumer-1}, body={group_id=RHAdpuiv}), createdTimeMs=1492686107041, sendTimeMs=1492686107041), responseBody={error_code=15,coordinator={node_id=-1,host=,port=-1}})
    2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG NetworkClient:640 - Sending metadata request {topics=[ByjSIH]} to node 1003
    2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG Metadata:180 - Updated cluster metadata version 7 to Cluster(nodes = [192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = ByjSIH, partition = 0, leader = 1003, replicas = [1003,], isr = [1003,]])
    2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:476 - Sending coordinator request for group RHAdpuiv to broker 192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)
    2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:489 - Received group coordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1492686107144, disconnected=false, request=ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@2a40cd94, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=10,api_version=0,correlation_id=11,client_id=consumer-1}, body={group_id=RHAdpuiv}), createdTimeMs=1492686107144, sendTimeMs=1492686107144), responseBody={error_code=15,coordinator={node_id=-1,host=,port=-1}})
    2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG NetworkClient:640 - Sending metadata request {topics=[ByjSIH]} to node 1003
```

The only ways I have to solve the situations are:

- Kill kafka and its storage (so the metadata about topics is gone)
- Change the consumer group id

Is there any other way to solve this situation that does not involve the above?

Comment: You can commit 0 offsets for all topic partitions in your consumer group

Comment: How's that possible... I get that behavior when trying to join the cluster. How can I even commit?

Comment: zookeeper-shell.sh script has a way to do that. Perhaps, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791268/how-to-change-start-offset-for-topic

Comment: oh ok, thought you were talking about using the kafka api

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is seeking to the beginning of the topic.

I think a safe way to do this in a dirty metadata state would be to do this:

```
consumer.seekToBeginning(Collections.emptySet()) // Rewind (lazy) all assigned partitions
consumer.poll(0) // Actually rewind by forcing a poll
```