# How change Kafka committed consumer offset with required offset

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have Kafka Stream application. My application is processing the events successfully.

How to change Kafka committed consumer offset with required offset to reprocess/skip the events. I tried  [How to change start offset for topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791268/how-to-change-start-offset-for-topic). But I got 'Node does not exist:' error. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

The question/answer you are referring to is based on an older Kafka version. Since Kafka 0.9, offsets are not committed to ZooKeeper but store in a special Kafka topic called the *offset topic* (topic name is `__consumer_offsets`).

Since Kafka 1.0, the command line tool `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh` has a new feature that allow to set offsets. Check out the original KIP: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-122%3A+Add+Reset+Consumer+Group+Offsets+tooling

The tool also works for Kafka 0.11 (and maybe even older Kafka versions).

An alternative is to write your own tool, that uses an single `KafkaConsumer` with the corresponding `group.id`, subscribe to the topic(s) you want to modify offsets for, `seek()` and `commit()` offsets. (Note, you should disable auto commit for this consumer.)

Comment: I tried to reset the offset as per document. But I got unrecognized option exception. My Kafka verstion is 0.10.2.0 Command is: `/home/centos/kafka_2.12-0.10.2.0/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server 1.1.1.1:9092,1.1.1.2:9092 --reset-offsets --group sample-app-0.0.1 --topic abc --to-offset 76756952` Exception: `Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: reset-offsets is not a recognized option`. Is this option not available in 0.10.2.0.

Comment: Because you call `kafka_2.12-0.10.2.0/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.s‌​h` you are using the old tool. You need to download Kafka 1.0 and use the tool from there.