# Is it possible for a consumer to start reading messages from a broker after a set date? For example only read messages after Jan 1st 2023

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a unique situation where we have a kafka broker running since last 5 years. I have to spin up a new consumer but i know for sure that records/messages before 2023 are useless to me. Is there a way I can start reading records from Jan 1st 2023?

can the seek api help here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change start offset for topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791268/how-to-change-start-offset-for-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `seek` method after calling `offsetsForTimes` can help.

By default, non-compacted Kafka topics only hold data for 7 days, however.